# Probability of an event

Tags: machine-learning, python, statistics, probability

How should I go about solving the following problem?

> If you randomly type a 6-digit number on a note, what is the
> probability that you can see the same number if you flip your note
> upside down? How would you explain your answer to a 6-year-old?

The only piece I have been able to calculate is that there are 9x10x10x10x10x10 numbers.

Is this correct? and/or what is the correct way to get the answer to this problem?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the number to be same when seen upside down:

1. *It can only contain either 0,1,8,6,9.*
2. *For first and last digit* :
   For it to be a 6 digit number first digit and the last digit cannot be 0.
   If first digit is 6 then last should be 9 and vice-versa.
   If first digit is other than 6 or 9 (ie. 1,8) then they both should have same digit.
3. *For second and fifth digit / *For third and fourth digit** :
   If first digit is 6 then last should be 9 and vice-versa.
   If first digit is other than 6 or 9 (ie. 1,8) then they both should have same digit.

**Total Number of 6 digit numbers** = 9 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10  *([9] as first digit cannot be 0)*

**Numerator** = 4 * 5 * 5 *([4] as first and last digit cant be 0)*

So,
Probability should be = Numerator / Total number of 6  digit numbers

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and an explanation. I think there could be one modification in point 1 of point 2 _For it to be a 6 digit number first digit and the last digit cannot be 0_ - The last digit can be 0 for it to be a six-digit number. What do you think?

Comment: If the last digit is 0 , then when we reverse it ,the resulting number will not be a 6 digit number. Also for it to be same when seen upside down its first and last digit should be same.    Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, very much. Thanks a lot!